# Arc reference to member of field

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to spawn a given set of threads and have each perform a long running operation. I would be passing a structure to each worker thread as the internal state of the given thread. The collection of said structs is kept in a vector, part of a `Master` struct.

The compiler rejects me passing the internal member of a struct to `Arc::new()`:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Worker {
   name: String,
}

struct Master {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
}

impl Worker {
    fn start(&self) {
        println!("My name is {} and I'm working!", self.name);
        thread::sleep_ms(100_000);
    }
}

impl Master {
    pub fn run_test(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..10 {
            self.workers.push(Worker { 
                name: String::new() + "Worker" + &i.to_string() 
            });
        }
        let mut data = Arc::new(self.workers);

        for i in 0..10 {
            let local_data = data.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                local_data[i].start();
            });
        }

        thread::sleep_ms(100_000);
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut master = Master { workers: vec![] };
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> <anon>:26:33
   |
26 |         let mut data = Arc::new(self.workers);
   |                                 ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this idiomatic Rust?

Comment: What exactly do you want to manage with that `Arc`? The `workers` vector? `Arc` needs ownership of the thing it manages, but you can't provide ownership, because you only have a borrow of the vector. There are [plenty of questions with the error message "cannot move out of borrowed content"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+%22cannot+move+out+of+borrowed+content%22) already. Maybe one of those can help you?

Comment: Also: string interpolation in Rust is usually not done via the `+` operator, but with `format!()`. You can replace your strange line with `name: format!("Worker{}", i)`. This does the same, looks cleaner and avoids unnecessary heap allocations.

Comment: I am indeed trying to manage the worker vector. My idea was that each thread would be a worker, and keep a worker struct as it's internal state, while at the same time the master keeps a reference to the vector of workers.

Comment: @Dash83: You were so close to the solution! I suggest you find a [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to help you in the future, somewhat talking aloud about your assumptions help highlight the funky bits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to Ownership.

In Rust, any single piece of data has *one and exactly one* owner. Don't be fooled by `Rc` and `Arc`: they are a shared interface on top of a single (invisible) owner.

The simplest way of expressing ownership is *by value*:

```
struct Master {
    workers: Vec<Worker>
}
```

Here, `Master` owns a `Vec<Worker>` which itself owns multiple `Worker`.

Similarly, functions that take their argument by value (`fn new(t: T) -> Arc<T>` for example) receive ownership of their argument.

And that is where the issue lies:

```
Arc::new(self.workers)
```

means that you are, at the same time:

- claiming that `Master` is the owner of `workers`
- claiming that `Arc` is the owner of `workers`

Given the rule of *one and exactly one* owner, this is clearly intractable.

---

So, how do you cheat and have multiple co-owners for a single piece of data?

Well... use `Rc` or `Arc`!

```
struct Master {
    workers: Arc<Vec<Worker>>
}
```

And now creating `data` is as simple as:

```
let data = self.workers.clone();
```

which creates a new `Arc` (which just bumps the reference count).

---

That's not quite all, though. The core tenet of the Borrowing system is: **Aliasing XOR Mutability**.

Since `Arc` is about aliasing, it prevents mutability. You cannot insert workers into `self.workers` any longer!

There are multiple solutions, such as deferring the initialization of `self.workers` until the vector is built, however the most common is to use cells or mutexes, that is `Rc<RefCell<T>>` or `Arc<Mutex<T>>` (or `Arc<RwLock<T>>`).

`RefCell` and `Mutex` are wrappers that move borrow checking from compile-time to run-time. This gives a bit more flexibility, but may result in run-time panics instead of compile-time errors, so is best used as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you, @Matthieu, insightful answers as always. However, I'm stumped now. Truth be told is, I don't need this shared collection of workers and start threads for each one, I could have created a separate worker binary that takes parameters for startup and then spawn the processes and forget about ownership, but since Rust promotes fearless concurrency, I opted to give that a shot.However, moving the issue from the compiler to runtime does not seem fearless. Is there a way to achieve the desired effect with compiler checks? Or am I simply looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: @Dash83: Fearless means that the language has your back (at either compile time or runtime), though I do too tend to prefer compile time checks rather than panicking binaries. Since you are not modifying `workers` in the thread, you can use a crate like `crossbeam` which supports referencing stack data from multiple threads, and you will no longer need `Arc` at all. Another solution is to copy the `Worker`. Yet another is to have `Master` relinquish ownership of `Worker` (`for w in self.workers.drain() { ... }`... it really depends on your constraints :)

Comment: you sir, are a scholar. Crossbeam scopes work great for this initial proof of concept. Not sure I'll stick with that crate in the long run, as I would rather learn the best practices for concurrency in Rust and design good code around them, but it works for now! Thanks!

Comment: I would say Crossbeam helps promoting good code :) Rust used to have the ability to reference stack-allocated data across threads, however the implementation relied on the fact that destructors would always be called and a PoC was made that you could manage to leak the destructor in order to have the stack-allocated data vanish was still referenced... creating a crash with safe code. Ouch. Since then, multiple crates have popped up to explore options to restore this capability: crossbeam & rayon are both written by different core team members (and explore different directions/usecases).